# Find all elements containing a value in an attribute

Tags: javascript

I use this to take some attributes:

```
window.document.getElementsByClassName("atbk")
```

However the class atbk is used in different elements. I would like to keep the attributes which only have in their href a common word `/url`

I tried this:

```
window.document.getElementsByClassName("atbk").href.indexOf("/url")
```

but it is not helpful. Is there anything I could do?

Comment: @Abhitalks—the OP seems to want class "atbk" and href contains "/url".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the css selector `[href*="/url"]` to select elements containing a substring in an attribute.

```
window.document.querySelectorAll('.atbk[href*="/url"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var list = window.document.getElementsByClassName("atbk");
var newlist =[];
for (z = 0; z < list.length; z++)
{
     if (list[z].href.indexOf('/url') > -1) 
     {
         newlist.push(list[z]);
     }
}

// use newlist...
```